# In LibreOffice Basic, how to condition for a non-empty string variable

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I recently started using Macros in Libreoffice Calc and stumbled upon a quite basic problem, I simply can't find a solution to. I want to check if a string variable is non-empty in an if ... then condition

Currently in a Macro for Libreoffice Calc the code reads in 6 cells as variables

```
    for I = 1 to 6
    column(I) = oDoc.Sheets.getByName(K).getCellByPosition(I-1,J).String    'read column 1-6
    next I
```

checks for some conditions

```
if column(4) = "" OR column(5) = "" OR column(6) != "" then
```

then writes those strings into new cells.

```
for I = 1 to 6
oDoc.Sheets.getByName("evalution").getCellByPosition(I,currentline+2).setString(column(I))
next I
```

if the conditions are not meat an else ... then moves the read entries somewhere else and writes them down there. By working in a loop of increasing J per sheet K and working trough all sheets K I can go trough the whole document an paste the lines with those 6 entries in a sorted in the evalution sheet.

If cells are empty, then when read the string is also just empty so I can check with = "".
But I can't find any way to check if the cell was not empty, so the string has anything in it and is not null.
I tried with a simple NOT condition so column(6) NOT = "" then, but no matter where I would place the NOT, LibreOffice always spits out an error. I tried using != like in the example as another way to negate the condition. Then the other way around tried if I could use = "*" or = "\w" as placeholder for any character. Nothing worked.
After also googling quite a bit and finding nothing to my problem, I turn to the hivemind of the internet itself, if anyone can help me.

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps you wanted to write **column(6) <> ""** instead of **column(6) != ""**?

Comment: oh this works, thanks. Wouldn't have guessed I could use size comparison operator would work for strings. But yeah it works like I wished, cool.

Comment: You could use the function `StrComp(s1, s2)`. This returns 0 (i.e. false) if the two strings are the same.  Or you could test for an empty cell by getting the cell's `CellContentType` struct, e.g. `If  oCell.getType() = CellContentType_EMPTY Then ...`, where `oCell  = oDoc.Sheets.getByName("whatever").getCellByPosition(i - 1, j)`.